# BIOS stuck in loop

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bios

I installed linux mint on one of my lenovo desktops, but after I remove the installer USB and reboot, I get this error:

[image]

I'm pretty sure that its because the boot order is set to the USB.

But when I try to change it by going into BIOS, I run into the same error. This is my startup selection screen. When I press F1, I run into the same issue as before so its basically a loop that keeps sending me back to the USB.

How can I resolve this issue?

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answer su-tiger86. I have managed to get into the 
[startup sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC7Tn.jpg).

Now I don't get the Intel Error, but just a black screen.

Comment: Actually, it is trying to do a network boot, but can't contact any host providing said services.

Can you show us what your startup menu has?  If your BIOS is setup like I think it is, you probably have more than one boot priority setup (Automatic, Error, etc), so images of each would help.

Comment: @Service Manager I have already attached that picture in the line: "This is the picture of my startup selection screen". Is that what you mean?

Comment: We need to see the order of devices your laptop can boot from.  When you get that screen again, hit F1, and you should find a Boot menu.  This will list the devices that are configured for booting, and which has priority.

Comment: But that's the problem, hitting F1 or any other option just leads me to the same error

Comment: @ServiceManager I have managed to get into the startup sequence now. Added the image in the edit

Answer (score 0):

If pressing F1 is your desktop pc's way of resuming to load after an error you likely must replace the CMOS (complimentary metal oxide semiconductor) battery. This would allow you to store BIOS (basic input/output system) settings like boot order. The likeliness is that you changed the pc boot order, however, upon restarting the pc was unable to keep the data stored to complete the specified boot order you had placed. Having that said, get a flat-head screwdriver and a ESD (electrostatic discharge) wristband and open your desktop pc, expose the motherboard to find the silver coin-looking battery and using the flat-head screwdriver carefully remove the battery and replace with the appropriate battery type.

Then, close up the destop pc, after putting things back together turn it on and enter the BIOS. Set the time and date and your boot order settings and disable the network boot option if you'd like it to omit trying to look for a terminal server, then save and quit.

Upon completing this you should be able to boot up your OS (Operating System) from whichever storage device you set, presuming you had installed it correctly and that the storage medium was partitioned correctly.

Comment: Also, I noticed someone state that hitting F1 will give you the boot menu, this is misleading. If you'd like to use such a temporal method, pressing F12 is the common button to display all storage and network boot mediums in which you may choose to boot from.

However, this is a temporary solution, once you turn off your pc and switch it back on you will need to do the whole process over again.

Comment: That was me.  The reason I stated that, was because he (originally) had a screen shot showing `Press F1 to load BIOS`, and `Press F12 to load boot menu`.
Thankfully though, your battery suggestion was able to help him.